# Why curl of a vector field that is proportional to $1/r^2$ equal to $0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator, curl

The curl of the vector field ${\bf F} = (-y {\bf i} + x {\bf j})/(x^2 + y^2)$ is $0$.

I have an intuitive understanding of why the divergence of a *radial* field that is proportional to 1/r^2 is equal to 0 (because for a spherical polar volume element the face farthest from the origin has a surface area that grows proportional to r^2 but the field strength decreases proportional to 1/r^2 so the effects cancel).

My lecture notes try to use a similar argument for the curl scenario, but I thought the curl represented the **line integral** around an infinitesimal element. If this is the case, the length of the plane polar sidelength farthest from the origin should increase proportional to $r$ (as $L = r\, d\theta$) but the field would decrease proportional to $1/r^2$ and they should not cancel.

Where is my misunderstanding?

[image of the vector field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMAa8.png)

Answer (score 0):

My own possible thinking is that rewritten in plane polar form, **F**=**θ^**/r (since -y**i**+x**j**/(x^2+y^2)^0.5 = **θ^**) and therefore the field strength does die off proportional to 1/r after all, thereby cancelling with the increased side length proportional to r and producing 0 curl.

In other words, x^2+y^2 = r^2 = r*r, where one of the r's is used to normalise the theta vector, and the other r causes a field strength decrease proportional to r.

I'm not sure how correct this thinking is though.